# .NET CORE with Node.js and webpack or browserify

Tags: node.js, .net-core, webpack, browserify

For days I am trying to make .NET CORE work with node. I tried webpack and browserify and nothing works.

The interesting thing is I can see my function definition in the resulting webpack javascript file, but I can't call it.

---

**Edit :**

Not the default .NET React App in Visual Studio. Just a normal .NET Web App, add a folder that contains all node stuff and build it with webpack. Will result a .js file that I import it in my .NET Web App. I don't need node.js for UI development, I just need it to make some UI JS function calls to node modules for ethereum blockchain that are not available in `<script type="text/javascript" src="web3.min.js"></script>`. Only available with `import { ethers } from "ethers";` or `var ethers = require('ethers');`

---

**temp.js**

```
function log(){
  console.log("log from node");
}

module.exports = log;
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@aliasName': path.resolve(__dirname, '../wwwroot/tempFolder')
    },
    modules: [
      'node_modules',
      path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules'),
    ],
  },
  mode: 'production',
  entry: '../wwwroot/tempFolder/temp.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'temp_bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../wwwroot/tempFolder'),
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    library: 'EntryPoint'
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  }
};
```

**CMD on Windows:**

```
browserify temp.js -o temp_bundle.js

npx webpack --config webpack.config.js
```

**dotnet CORE index.cshtml**

```
<script src="temp_bundle.js"></script>
<script>log()</script>
```

**ERROR:**

```
ReferenceError: log is not defined
    at functionName ((index):170:13)
```

Comment: what do you mean as "make dotnet core work with node"? if you mean an app (e.g. ASP NET Core/NET6/NET7) using node for building the frontend (e.g. React and Typescript), then I use it daily since years and it works like a charm.

Comment: Not the default .NET React App in Visual Studio. Just a normal .NET Web App, add a folder that contains all node stuff and build it with webpack. Will result a .js file that I import it in my .NET Web App. I don't need node.js for UI development, I just need it to make some UI JS function calls to node modules for ethereum blockchain.